# mvc.net project local setup

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have an asp.net mvc project and I'm trying to complete a local setup. I have made an entry in the local host file and updated binding in the config file.

But when I try to execute I'm getting error:

> Make sure the web address is correct.

Can anyone please help out?

Comment: What binding you have updated in config file and what entry you made in local host?

Comment: 10.208.100.52 local.proposalweb.ext.hpi.com I have updated this in local host file .

Comment: also in start url of project https://local.proposalweb.ext.hpi.com:44304/

Comment: Are you doing this set up in your solution? You got to configure this in IIS..

Comment: In IIS ? shoudl I add new website ? I am new to asp.net I am learning

Comment: Then you got to watch some tutorials before starting things up.. Hope this link will help you to setup a website http://www.iisunderground.com/add-a-new-website-iis-7-5/.. Before getting into iis you got to publish your solution in some directory and map them in IIS by doing things step by step as described in the above link..

Comment: Its confusing a lot :/

Comment: we had got setup guidelines.

Comment: 1. I have made an entry in host file. 10.208.100.52 local.proposalweb.ext.hpi.com

Comment: 2. Updated config file 
<site name="HP.ProposalWeb" id="2"><application path="/" applicationPool="Clr4IntegratedAppPool">
                    <virtualDirectory path="/" physicalPath="E:\MVC\ProposalWeb-Inc (1)\ProposalWeb-Inc\ProposalWeb-Inc\HP.ProposalWeb" />
                </application>
                <bindings>
                    <binding protocol="http" bindingInformation="*:8080:local.proposalweb.ext.hpi.com" />
     <binding protocol="https" bindingInformation="*:44304:local.proposalweb.ext.hpi.com" />
                </bindings>
            </site>

Comment: 3. In visual studio. start URL: https://local.proposalweb.ext.hpi.com:44309/

Comment: 4. Project URL: https://localhost.proposalweb.ext.hpi.com:44309 but when I click create virtual directgory I get error now. Unalbe to create virtualdirectory. cannot create the website you must specify local host for the server name.